# How to delete a contact flow in Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-connect

It's easy to create or rename a contact flow in Amazon Connect, but how do you delete one? The documentation doesn't mention anything about it and a Google search has come up empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, in Amazon Connect, the only way to delete a flow is via API:

From the [Administrator Guide for Amazon Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/create-contact-flow.html):

> To delete flows use the DeleteContactFlow API.
>
> Currently, there's no way to delete flows using the Amazon Connect admin console.

Comment: Google shows this as first result, so it would be nice to update it, as currently you can delete flow using cli.

Answer (score 7):

AWS CLI now supports contact flow deletion.

From the [Documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/connect/delete-contact-flow.html):

```
    delete-contact-flow
--instance-id <value>
--contact-flow-id <value>
[--cli-input-json | --cli-input-yaml]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Edit:
Alternatively you can use the [DeleteContactFlow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteContactFlow.html) API.

Comment: CLI support is better than nothing. Thank you.